# jQuery triggering events within another event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I have encountered a problem where I cannot trigger a click event on a link from within a click event handler.  Please consider this example:

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
<a id="a" href="#a">A</a>
<a id="b" href="#b">B</a>
<script>
    $('#a').click(function() {
        //setTimeout(function() {
            $('#b')[0].click();
        //}, 100);
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

When the user clicks on the A link I would expect them to see #b in the address bar but this is not the case.  If I remove the comments it works.  Why can I not trigger an event within another event?  Is the setTimeout really necessary?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to prevent default behaviour:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s9Lnh/show)

```
$('#a').click(function (e) {  
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#b')[0].click(); //call click method of DOM node
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$('#a').click(function () {
    $('#b').click();
    return false;
});
```

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/b7KJg/)

Comment: i don't think this answer OP question